# Allow checking to a checkbox even after adding attr("checked", false)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am not sure if a formulated the title correctly but the logic is this. 
I have 4 checkboxes, **3 Yes** and *1 No*. Selecting 3 **Yes** will uncheck *No* and selecting *No* will uncheck **Yes**.
My jQuery as per below:

```
var yes = $("input[type=checkbox].yes");

if (yes.length == yes.filter(":checked").length) {
    $("#no").attr("checked", false);
} else if($("#no").is(":checked")) {
    yes.attr("checked", false);
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

It works. However, if I checked all **Yes**, I won't be able to select *No*. Instead, I need to uncheck 1 **Yes** to select *No*. Same thing for *No*. If I check *No*, all **Yes** will be unchecked. However I need to uncheck *No* to be able to select **Yes** again.
Will there be a way that I can still select *No* if all **Yes** is checked?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Including HTML now

```
<form id="checkbox-testing" >
<div class="checkform">
    <label>                        
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" value="Yes, 1" id="yes1"><span>&nbsp;Yes, 1</span> 
    </label>
    <label>                        
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" value="Yes, 2" id="yes2"><span>&nbsp;Yes, 2</span>
    </label>
    <label>                        
      <input class="yes" type="checkbox" value="Yes, 3" id="yes3"><span>&nbsp;Yes, 3</span>
    </label>
    <label>                        
      <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="no"><span>&nbsp;No</span>
    </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

Comment: @guradio. can you elaborate more please? thanks!

Comment: add your html as well in the op together with the js

Comment: if this is a binary state - either one or the other is to be checked then perhaps you should be using a radio button input

Comment: UPDATE - i just amended my answer to give a radio buton to select on or the other option and a button to clear the checked property on the click. if the state is to be one or the other  and the options are mutually exlcusve then a radio button input is better.

Comment: @gavgrif. user should be able to select multiple items, that's why a checkbox is used

Answer (score 0):

use .prop() to test the checked propert instead of .attr() - the following snippet uses .prop and then use a .change() event - in this case I am just conseol.logging the output but you can change the prop ofr the other checkbox.

EDIT - i just updated my answer to give a radio buton to select on or the other option and a button to clear the checked property on the click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){;
    console.log("yes: " + $(".yes").prop("checked"));
    console.log(" no: " + $(".no").prop("checked"));
  })
  
  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").prop('checked',false)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for ="yes">Yes
  <input type ="radio" name ="test" id="yes" class="yes" checked value"yes"/></label>
<label for ="no">No
  <input type ="radio" name ="test" id="no" class="no" value = "no"/>
  <hr/>
  
  
  <button type ="button" name ="test" id="clear" >Clear Value</button>
```

```
var yes = $("input[type=checkbox].yes");

if (yes.length == yes.filter(":checked").length) {
    $("#no").prop("checked", false);
} else if($("#no").is(":checked")) {
    yes.prop("checked", false);
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: hi @gavgrif. thanks but the output is still the same. i still need to uncheck 1 yes/no to select the other.

Comment: @thebeast22, it would be better if you update your question with the `HTML` too.